# How to write $ uv^{\top} + vu^{\top} $ as $ xx^{\top} + yy^{\top} $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

I'm wondering, if it's possible to bring every $ uv^{\top} + vu^{\top} $, where $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $ in the form of $ xx^{\top} + yy^{\top} $, with 
$x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $, since $ rank(uv^{\top} + vu^{\top}) = 2.$

Is there a explicit formula for such a decomposition? I tried to calculate it directly on paper, but need to calculate a nonlinear equation system. Is there a trick or an idea, what I could do to find such a formula?

Comment: $\operatorname{rank}(uv^T+vu^T) \leq 2$. The rank is 1 when $v = u$.

Answer (score 5):

No.

$xx^T + yy^T$ is positive semi definite but  $uv^T + vu^T$ need not be. Consider $u = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$

Answer (score 5):

In general $u v^T + v u^T$ might not be positive semidefinite, so you wouldn't have such a decomposition.   However you can write $u v^T + v u^T = x x^T - y y^T$, where $x = (u+v)/\sqrt{2}$ and $y = (u-v)/\sqrt{2}$.

In fact, the only case where $u v^T + v u^T$ is positive semidefinite is when $u$ and $v$ are linearly dependent.  Otherwise you could take $w$ such that
$w^T (u + v) = 0$ while $w^T u \ne 0$, and $w^T (u v^T + v u^T) w = - 2 (w^T u)(w^T v) < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Notable fact to supplement the answers: we can rewrite these matrices as
$$
\pmatrix{u&v}\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} \pmatrix{u&v}^T, \qquad
\pmatrix{x&y} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} \pmatrix{x&y}^T
$$
we may then reach Robert Israel's conclusion using [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia).